Stability of a random variable with respect to coverage
I define a random variable $X$ to be stable if, for any non-random real intervals $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$
P(X \in A) \geq 0.9 \quad \text{and} \quad P(X \in B) \geq 0.9,
$$
it holds that
$$
P(2X \in A + B) \geq 0.9,
$$
where $A + B = \{a + b : a \in A, b \in B\}$.
Question: Is Gaussian random variable or Exponential random variable stable? Can you maybe give some better characterization when a variable is stable?
A nice non-stable example is when $X$ is discrete, $P(X=-1) = 0.1, P(X=0)=0.8, P(X=1)=0.1$. Then, sets $A=[-1, 0]$ and $B=[0,1]$ contradict stability of $X$.
